# Ruby on Rails pagination Specify Sort By Order By on view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sorting, pagination

In my rails application I am limiting the amount of products displayed on a page to 6 through pagination, what I want to be able to do is allow the user to order/sort the results to either ascending or descending. I think I will need a drop down menu to do this, and then pass this data over to my products_controller maybe through an instance variable.

At the minute in my application.html.erb view I have this for a drop down menu:

```
<div id="order-by">
     <select>
        <option value="asc">Ascending</option>
        <option value="des">Descending</option>
      </select>
</div>
```

But am unsure how to pass over the selected value to my products_controller.rb, and in my products_controller.rb I have this for ordering at the minute:

```
  def index
   @products = Product.order(:title).page(params[:page]).per(6)
 end
```

Can anyone please help? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass sorting parameter to your controller as part of the GET request. Controller will need to extract this param from request and apply to the sorting.

You can use either a form with GET  or use javascript to adjust the URI before sending the request.

Comment: How can I do this? I'm pretty new to ruby

Comment: Simplest option for you to try would be to add "onchange" event to the select box and when user selects the options you change you append the selected parameter to the url and refresh the page using window.location. Something like: window.location = window.location +"?sortOrder='+selected_value

Comment: Sorry I'm new to Ruby on Rails, can you edit my code to show me what it should look like please.

Answer (score 0):

A quick hack here

```
<div id="order-by" onchange="sort()">
     <select>
        <option value="asc">Ascending</option>
        <option value="des">Descending</option>
      </select>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    /*This can be simplified using JQuery etc*/
    function sort(){
        var selected=document.getElementById('order-by');
        var val = selected.options[selected.selectedIndex].value;

        window.location =  window.location + "?orderBy="+val;

    }

</script>

Then in the rails controller, you can access the parameter as :

ortOrder = params[:orderBy]
```